# Partial Differentiation of Vector Norm

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, partial-derivative

Given is $\gamma||\vec{a}||^2$, $\vec{a} \in \mathbb{R}^d, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}$

I want to partially differentiate: $\frac{\partial}{\partial a_1} \gamma ||\vec{a}||^2$,

Can I just assume that  $||\vec{a}||^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2$, and hence $\frac{\partial}{\partial a_1} \gamma ||\vec{a}||^2 = 2 \gamma a_1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you did is correct.

A consequence of what you did is you have proven that

$$\frac{d}{da}\gamma\|a\|^2=2\gamma a$$

Comment: Ah that was actually also just my follow up question, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if $\vec{a}=(a_1,...,a_n)$ then $\frac{\partial}{\partial a_i} \gamma ||\vec{a}||^2 = 2 \gamma a_i$.

Comment: Quick follow up question, what if I derive the entire term (gamma included) w.r.t. to a (and not only a component of a)?